# How do i group items by key in a multi dimension array with php

Tags: php, arrays, group-by

I have an array with data that i would want to group, example below:

```
[

{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emmission": 3450
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emmission": 91
},
{
    "date": "09-02-2016",
    "emmission": 10
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emmission": 7
},
{
    "date": "19-04-2016",
    "emmission": 28
},
{
    "date": "08-05-2015",
    "emmission": 7
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emmission": 15
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emmission": 109
}

]
```

What i am trying to do is group them together by date and calculate the emmission value(sum by date);

thus the duplicated array like: {
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emmission": 3450
}

should only exists once and the emmission should be sum, i have tried almost everything from array_unique to array_search but still no luck.

Thanks

What i have now

```
public function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 

    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$i] = $val; 

             // $temp_array[$i]['emmission'] += $array[$i]['emmission'];
        }

        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
} 

$this->unique_multidim_array($history, 'date');
```

With that i get unique dates but the emmission for the last element is zero

Comment: *i have tried almost everything* Just show your best attempt. This way we can easily show you where you got stuck and how to solve it.

Comment: Oke i will add it now

Comment: You already have a few things in the right direction. What you essentially want to do is: Loop through your array and use the date as a key for a second(temp) array. Then you want to check in the loop if you already have an element in the second array with the date as key and if note create that element with date as key and set the value to 0. Then you always add the emission to the element with date as key and done. (If you don't want the dates as keys you can reindex the array afterwards with `array_values()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one typo: "emmission" is spelled "emission"

a possible solution would use two loops. First to sum all the emissions grouped by date as a key, and then second to rebuild the object.

```
<?php
$json = '[

{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emission": 3450
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emission": 91
},
{
    "date": "09-02-2016",
    "emission": 10
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emission": 7
},
{
    "date": "19-04-2016",
    "emission": 28
},
{
    "date": "08-05-2015",
    "emission": 7
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emission": 15
},
{
    "date": "04-06-2016",
    "emission": 109
}

]';

$arr_obj = json_decode($json);

// for each record, if date emission is set, then sum, else set emission
foreach ($arr_obj as $record)
  $dates[$record->date] = isset($dates[$record->date]) ? $dates[$record->date] + $record->emission : $record->emission;

// create array of objects
foreach ($dates as $key => $val)
  $obj_arr []= (object) array("date"=>$key,"emission"=>$val);

$json = json_encode($obj_arr);

echo $json;
```

Results in this output:

```
[{"date":"04-06-2016","emission":3672},{"date":"09-02-2016","emission":10},{"date":"19-04-2016","emission":28},{"date":"08-05-2015","emission":7}]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, i will turn it into a function.